# CakePHP - HABTM Multiple Records to Same Model

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp, relationship

I am attempting to use the HABTM association within CakePHP to join multiple records from the same model, to one record from another model.

The models I am attempting to associate are User and Bet. The user model is fairly standard, the difficult is the bet model. The bet record has, amongst other things, an ID, plus a column for user_1_id and user_2_id. Each bet has two participants.

At first I thought storing these two in the same record within the bet table would be fine, with a simple hasMany association in the user model, along with a finder query as I have two foreign keys:

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Bet' => array(
        'className' => 'Bet',
        'foreign_key' => false,
        'finderQuery' => 'SELECT *
                            FROM `bets` as `Bet`
                            WHERE `Bet`.`user_1_id` IN ({$__cakeID__$})
                            OR `Bet`.`user_2_id` IN ({$__cakeID__$})',
    ),
```

However, like I said I ran into some difficulties, and it appeared as though the relationship was only working in one direction (i.e. I can view user details when working with an individual bet, but when working with users I cannot associate with bet details).

So now I believe I will need a HABTM relationship, with a join table, what I am not sure of is how I am going to make it work to store multiple records of the same model, as well as one of another model, within the link table.

This is making my head hurt, so any outside perspectives or advice would be really helpful indeed,
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this myself. I had got my associations all wrong it seems.
I stumbled across this in the Cake Book: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#multiple-relations-to-the-same-model

Not sure how I didn't realise this earlier, as I am using the exact same association elsewhere in my app to handle a followers system. The key is to use an alias for the model, as it explains in detail in the guide.

Hopefully this will serve to help somebody else in the future!